# Android issue with rendering emoji

Tags: android, textview, android-textview-autosize

I have textfield that I am setting text string and observing strange issue

If the string is "" which is codepoints  128591 1f64f I see this image1

[image]

But if the string is "" which is basically 2 code points with values 128591 128591, I see this image

[image]

Is there something special I need to do in order for the first emoji to get rendered correctly in a textView?

The emoji in question is - https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/emoticons/1f64f/person-with-folded-hands/

I am using appCompat 1.4.1 and I am use AppCompatTextView to render text.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji2

Comment: But I am using appCompat 1.4.1 if I am reading that page correctly, I don't need to use that specific emoji library, or am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should show code and UTF-8 values of your string along with how you are testing (emulator/device/OS version).

Comment: EMOJI   : :pray::pray:
D EMOJI   : Spannable length 4 String len 4 Codepoint count 2 
D EMOJI   : UTF_8 0 0xf0 1 0x9f 2 0x99 3 0x8f 4 0xf0 5 0x9f 6 0x99 7 0x8f
D EMOJI   : UTF_16 0 0xf0 1 0x9f 2 0x99 3 0x8f 4 0xf0 5 0x9f 6 0x99 7 0x8f
D EMOJI   : CodePoint 0 0x1f64f 1 0x1f64f

I am using emulator API 31 and physical phone Pixel 4a with Android 13
I see the same results.

Comment: 1) [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73595754/edit) your question with your details/responses. 2) So you are using [EmojiTextView](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji-compat#library-components)?

Comment: Updated original question, from what I understand one doesn't need to use EmojiTextView if one is using AppCompatTextView and latest appCompat. Do you know otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Above issue was because I was setting wrong length on spannable string that had emoji.

I distilled the code down to following

```
val spannableText = SpannableString("x\uD83D\uDE4F")
val urlSpan = URLSpan("https://www.google.com/")
spannableText.setSpan(
    urlSpan,
    1,
    2,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
)
```

That produces output that looks like this:

[image]

In above example if I set start and end position of the span "correctly" over the entire emoji things look correct.

```
val spannableText = SpannableString("x\uD83D\uDE4F")
val urlSpan = URLSpan("https://www.google.com/")
spannableText.setSpan(
    urlSpan,
    1,
    3,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
)
```

I have code that builds complex spannable, so I got computation of span length wrong when there is codepoint/emoji in the string.

I "distilled" my issue above. Posting an update here, in case someone runs into this in the future.